# Como salvo esta imagem na galeria e acessá-la novamente?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Eu tenho este Xamarin Android App (não Forms) que apenas abre a câmera e permite-me tirar uma foto e ir com ele ou retomar. Depois que eu digo que quero mantê-lo, ele aparece no aplicativo em um ImageView usando um bitmap. Não foi possível salvá-lo na galeria usando o bitmap. Eu preciso que seja capaz de salvar na galeria para que eu possa fazer um novo botão mais tarde, que obtém a última foto tirada (aquela tirada com o aplicativo) e envia para um servidor (eu poderia usar alguma ajuda sobre isso também). e isso é tudo que eu preciso fazer.
Aqui está o código MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;

using Android.Widget;

using Android.OS;

using Android.Content;

using Android.Provider;

using Android.Runtime;

using Android.Graphics;

namespace CameraApp

{

    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity

    {

        ImageView imageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Button btnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);

            imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

            btnCamera.Click += BtnCamera_Click;

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)

        {

            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }

    }

}
```